# Javascript Regex Test Function: *OR* syntax

Tags: javascript, regex, string, syntax

```
if(/categories/.test(url)) {  ... }
```

I'm using the above code to check whether `url` contains the string "categories". What is the syntax for checking to see if `url` container the string "categories" OR "character"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if(/(categories)|(character)/.test(url)) {  ... }
```

As shown on [here](http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/), the 'pipe' (`|`), denotes OR in a regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

The vertical pipe `|` denotes "or" in regular expressions

```
if(/categories|character/.test(url)) {  ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(/(categories|character)/.test(url)) {  ... }
```

...should work.

I find this resource very helpful when dealing with regular expressions:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: It can be used for global matching. It doesn't make sense using the test-function, so I removed it again. I was a little confused by a comment about it, that was later deleted :)

Answer (score 2):

You dont need regex for that

String functions are enough for that.

```
if(url.indexOf("categories")>0 || url.indexOf("character")>0){
// your code.
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this traverse the string twice if it doesn't contain "categories"? Is it still better with string functions then?

Comment: Is this faster than using regex? Thanks by the way-- I was trying to get the if statement to work earlier with indexOf() and couldn't -- but your method with ">0" did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: i wish I could vote more than once for this... you answered the more important question that I didn't ask!

Comment: @j-man86 The regular expression will traverse full string to find both. But this string search will just first check categories. And it's fast.

Answer (score 1):

`if(/(categories | character)/.test(url)) { ... }`